# Are ASP.NET-MVC4 and AngularJs work well together?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Is the combination of technological ASP.NET-MVC4, and AngularJs work well?
About the needs of my app: most of the work of my application view pages with tables of information. 
I need to have an easy option to identify each point in the tables on the client side, highlight it, paint it, and request additional information from the server about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC and Angular.js have nothing in common.

Short answer is yes - they work well together.

You would simply make all your Actions respond with JSON rather than HTML (unless you want HTML in some scenarios)

i.e you write your HTML template, angular controller, etc on the client, and have an Action to grab all the table records as JSON, then load that in your angular controller to populate the table, interact with it all on the client, and send any changes back to the server.

You could replace Angular with any client-side technology if you wanted. Backbone, Knockout, etc.